# c++ socket programming: bind() fails

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, bind, winsock

I'm trying to construct a simple UDP network program in C++ to establish a real-time data communication platform between two computers in my company.

The below code is for Server (receiver), and I successfully tested the network self-communication (IP='127.0.0.1').

However, if I change the IP number corresponding to another computer (147.47.42.50), I face a binding failure error.

When I type 'ping' in cmd, it successfully returns responses.

Is there any incorrect logic in my program? and is there any way to debug this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ServerSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN ServerInfo;
    SOCKADDR_IN FromClient;

    int FromClient_Size;
    int Recv_Size;
    int Send_Size;
    int Count;

    char Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    short ServerPort = 6000;

    if (WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "WinSock initialization fail. " << endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    memset(&ServerInfo, 0, sizeof(ServerInfo));
    memset(&FromClient, 0, sizeof(FromClient));
    memset(Buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    ServerInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("147.47.42.50");
    ServerInfo.sin_port = htons(ServerPort);

    ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (ServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) //
    {
        cout << "Cannot create socket." << endl;
        closesocket(ServerSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    if (bind(ServerSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&ServerInfo,
        sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Bind fail." << endl;
        closesocket(ServerSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        FromClient_Size = sizeof(FromClient);
        Recv_Size = recvfrom(ServerSocket, Buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
            (struct sockaddr*)&FromClient, &FromClient_Size);

        if (Recv_Size < 0)
        {
            cout << "recvfrom() error!" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        cout << "Receive! client IP: " << inet_ntoa(FromClient.sin_addr) << endl;
        cout << "Data: " << Buffer << endl;
    }
    closesocket(ServerSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Sockets can't bind to remote IP addresses.

Comment: Replace `ServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("147.47.42.50");` with `ServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;` and see how that goes.